# Caliburn.Micro Click Event To find Image Point and calculate Distance

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Hello I'm in a problem of finding the image point .My objective is when I click two point I have to find the distance between two point. Here is My code

`<ImageGrid.Row="3"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" x:Name="DIIMG2" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDown]=[Action GetImagePoint($eventArgs)]"></Image>`

Here you can see I  use MouseDown Event and When The Event Fire I cannot use X,Y coordinates to get the point value For Example The following Code

```
 public void GetImagePoint(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int myX = e.X;
        int myY = e.Y;

    }
```

I got compile error  like   'MouseEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'X' and no accessible extension method 'X' accepting a first argument of type 'MouseEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) . How to Overcome this . I need to find The X and Y value means co ordinate value . Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your WPF you define 2 arguments `GetImagePoint($source, $eventArgs)`,

and in your function to access at (X,Y), you use GetPosition method:

```
    public void GetImagePoint(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(sender is System.Windows.Controls.Image)) return;
        System.Windows.Point px = e.GetPosition((System.Windows.Controls.Image)sender);
        int myX = (int)px.X;
        int myY = (int)px.Y;
    }
```

I suggest you to check if mouseclick in on image:

Comment: No It is Not Solved yet . I cannot access int myX = e.X; ... e.X not able to access

Comment: you have to use tthe GetPosition method..see my fixed answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I think The namespace would be System.Drawing.Image In this line(System.Drawing.Point px = e.GetPosition((System.Drawing.Image)sender);) I got this compile time error cannot convert System.Drawing.Image to System.Windows.InputElement

Comment: hum for me namespace for Image is `System.Windows.Controls`. and `System.Windows`  for Point..  But its difficult to answer correctly without your complete program about your image you are loading

Comment: I'm Loading Image from BitmapImage Thanks I am trying